# MySQL: Improve SELECT-Statement: Select net amount for each tax rate in table more flexible

Tags: mysql

I have this table (positions), which contains positions of a bill (simplified):

```
+-----+---------+----------+-------+----------+
| id  | id_bill | quantity | price | tax_rate |
+-----+---------+----------+-------+----------+
| 1   | 1       | 1        |  5    |  7       |
| 2   | 1       | 1        |  10   |  19      |
| 3   | 2       | 2        |  4    |  16      |
| 4   | 2       | 1        |  8    |  19      |
| 5   | 2       | 1        |  6    |  5       |
| 6   | 2       | 1        |  5    |  7       |
| 7   | 3       | 1        |  7    |  5       |
| 8   | 4       | 2        |  5    |  19      |
| 9   | 5       | 3        |  8    |  16      |
+-----+---------+----------+-------+----------+
```

A bill can hold positions with 1 to 4 different tax rates (5%, 7%, 16%, 19%).
I would like to select the sum of amounts for each tax rate.

I got the following working SQL-Select, but it is very static and hard to adjust if a new tax rate comes up:

```
SELECT
    id_bill,
    SUM(ROUND(price*quantity, 2)) as amount_net_total,
    SUM(ROUND(IF(tax_rate=5, price*quantity, 0), 2)) as amount_net_5,
    SUM(ROUND(IF(tax_rate=7, price*quantity, 0), 2)) as amount_net_7,
    SUM(ROUND(IF(tax_rate=16, price*quantity, 0), 2)) as amount_net_16,
    SUM(ROUND(IF(tax_rate=19, price*quantity, 0), 2)) as amount_net_19,
    SUM(ROUND(price*quantity*((tax_rate+100)/100), 2)) as amount_gross_total 
FROM positions GROUP BY id_bill
```

Is it possible to get the net amount for each tax rate, which contains the table (assuming I don't know that there are only 4 different or for the case I have to add new tax rates):

[image: Result]

In text form (as requested):

```
+-----+---------+------------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| id  | id_bill | amount_net_total | amount_net_5 | amount_net_7 | amount_net_16 | amount_net_19 | amount_gross_total |
+-----+---------+------------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
| 1   | 1       | 15.00            |  0.00        |  5.00        |  0.00         | 10.00         | 17.25              |
| 3   | 2       | 27.00            |  6.00        |  5.00        |  8.00         |  8.00         | 30.45              |
| 7   | 3       |  7.00            |  7.00        |  0.00        |  0.00         |  0.00         |  7.35              |
| 8   | 4       | 10.00            |  0.00        |  0.00        |  0.00         | 10.00         | 11.90              |
| 9   | 5       | 24.00            |  0.00        |  0.00        | 24.00         |  0.00         | 27.84              |
+-----+---------+------------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

Sorry for my English, I hope my question is understandable.

As requested:

```
CREATE TABLE `positions` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_bill` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `quantity` decimal(7,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(7,3) NOT NULL,
  `tax_rate` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 19,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

LOCK TABLES `positions` WRITE;

INSERT INTO `positions` (`id`, `id_bill`, `quantity`, `price`, `tax_rate`)
VALUES
    (1,1,1.00,5.000,7),
    (2,1,1.00,10.000,19),
    (3,2,2.00,4.000,16),
    (4,2,1.00,8.000,19),
    (5,2,1.00,6.000,5),
    (6,2,1.00,5.000,7),
    (7,3,1.00,7.000,5),
    (8,4,2.00,5.000,19),
    (9,5,3.00,8.000,16);


UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: Please provide the desired result in tabular format

Comment: I updated my question with a result table

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text

Comment: In this case: Why not? It shows the desired output, so it fulfills its purpose, doesn't it?

Comment: I did what you asked for, but I still don't get it. It takes time and is not more readable.

Comment: Much better. However, I would argue that (the final part of) this kind of problem is best resolved in application code, e.g. PHP. Do you have access to anything like that?

Comment: Could you tell me, why this is much better (in text-form)? This is just a subquery of a much larger query. The question was if there is a better approach than the working one only using MySQL. You let me improve my question for 2 hours to give me an answer you could have told me right away. I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following (as I think you've already surmised) will return the desired result set; the rest of the problem (missing results and the pivot) is to my mind a display issue, best resolved in application code...

```
SELECT a.*
     , b.total 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT id_bill
            , tax_rate
            , SUM(quantity*price) net 
         FROM positions 
        GROUP 
           BY id_bill,tax_rate
     ) a 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT id_bill
            , SUM(quantity*price) total 
         FROM positions 
        GROUP 
           BY id_bill
     ) b 
    ON b.id_bill = a.id_bill
 ORDER
    BY id_bill
     , tax_rate;

+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| id_bill | tax_rate | net      | total    |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|       1 |        7 |  5.00000 | 15.00000 |
|       1 |       19 | 10.00000 | 15.00000 |
|       2 |        5 |  6.00000 | 27.00000 |
|       2 |        7 |  5.00000 | 27.00000 |
|       2 |       16 |  8.00000 | 27.00000 |
|       2 |       19 |  8.00000 | 27.00000 |
|       3 |        5 |  7.00000 |  7.00000 |
|       4 |       19 | 10.00000 | 10.00000 |
|       5 |       16 | 24.00000 | 24.00000 |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've just seen your answer.

Comment: :-D! A lot of work in a different project and no e-mail-notifications from stackoverflow. I just forgot about the problem, because I used a different approach.